# Why is this NVIDIA CUDA PTX not working as intended?

Tags: c++, cuda, ptx

I have this code that tries to add two vectors using a handwritten PTX function:

```
//kernel.cu
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>


int main()
{
    CUdevice device;
    CUcontext context;
    CUmodule module;
    CUfunction function;
    char* moduleFile = "test.ptx";
    char* kernelName = "test";

    CUresult err = cuInit(0);
    cuDeviceGet(&device, 0);
    cuCtxCreate(&context, 0, device);

    err = cuModuleLoad(&module, moduleFile);
    if (err != CUDA_SUCCESS) { printf("cuModuleLoad %4d \n", err); return 1; }

    err = cuModuleGetFunction(&function, module, kernelName);
    if (err != CUDA_SUCCESS) { printf("cuModuleGetFunction %4d \n", err); return 1; }


    int size = 4;
    unsigned int byteSize = size * sizeof(int);
    int* h_a = (int*)malloc(byteSize);
    int* h_b = (int*)malloc(byteSize);
    int* h_c = (int*)malloc(byteSize);
    CUdeviceptr d_a; cuMemAlloc(&d_a, byteSize);
    CUdeviceptr d_b; cuMemAlloc(&d_b, byteSize);
    CUdeviceptr d_c; cuMemAlloc(&d_c, byteSize);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        h_a[i] = i;
        h_b[i] = i;
        h_c[i] = 0;
    }
    printf("before\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("i:%-3d a:%-3d b:%-3d c:%-3d \n", i, h_a[i], h_b[i], h_c[i]);

    cuMemcpyHtoD(d_a, h_a, byteSize);
    cuMemcpyHtoD(d_b, h_b, byteSize);
    void* args[]{ &d_a, &d_b, &d_c };
    cudaLaunchKernel(function, { 1, 1, 1 }, { byteSize, 1, 1 }, (void**)args);

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cuMemcpyDtoH(h_c, d_c, byteSize);

    printf("\nafter\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("i:%-3d a:%-3d b:%-3d c:%-3d \n", i, h_a[i], h_b[i], h_c[i]);

    free(h_a);
    free(h_b);
    free(h_c);
    cuMemFree(d_a);
    cuMemFree(d_b);
    cuMemFree(d_c);

    cuCtxDestroy(context);
    cudaDeviceReset();
    return 0;
}
```

PTX function:

```
//test.ptx
.version 6.5
.target sm_75
.address_size 64

.visible .entry test(
    .param .u64 .ptr .global .align 8 a,
    .param .u64 .ptr .global .align 8 b,
    .param .u64 .ptr .global .align 8 c
)
{
    .reg .u64 %a;
    .reg .u64 %b;
    .reg .u64 %c;
    .reg .u64 %i;

    ld.param.u64 %a, [a];
    ld.param.u64 %b, [b];
    ld.param.u64 %c, [c];
    cvt.u64.u32 %i, %tid.x;
    shl.b64 %i, %i, 2;
    add.u64 %a, %a, %i;
    add.u64 %b, %b, %i;
    add.u64 %c, %c, %i;

    .reg .s32 %s<3>;
    ld.s32 %s0, [%a];
    ld.s32 %s1, [%b];
    add.s32 %s0, %s0, %s1;
    st.s32 [%c], %s0;

    ret;
}
```

The output is:

```
before
i:0   a:0   b:0   c:0
i:1   a:1   b:1   c:0
i:2   a:2   b:2   c:0
i:3   a:3   b:3   c:0
test took 52.0913 ms

after
i:0   a:0   b:0   c:0
i:1   a:1   b:1   c:0
i:2   a:2   b:2   c:0
i:3   a:3   b:3   c:0
```

when it should be:

```
before
i:0   a:0   b:0   c:0
i:1   a:1   b:1   c:0
i:2   a:2   b:2   c:0
i:3   a:3   b:3   c:0
test took 52.0913 ms

after
i:0   a:0   b:0   c:0
i:1   a:1   b:1   c:2
i:2   a:2   b:2   c:4
i:3   a:3   b:3   c:6
```

I am using the driver API to load the PTX file and run the kernel **test**. I believe it's either something with the way I'm using the cuda context or the way I'm loading and accessing the gpu memory. What am I missing?

Comment: What happens if you wrote a functionally equivalent kernel in CUDA C++, and compiled that to PTX and run it?

Comment: it works as intended. I looked at the ptx putput and..... it's functionally identical .... I still can't see the mistake

Comment: Why are you mixing driver and runtime API calls in the code? That is 99% certain not to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running your code with cuda-memcheck showed that the function launch was failing:

```
$ cuda-memcheck ./saitama
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
before
i:0   a:0   b:0   c:0   
i:1   a:1   b:1   c:0   
i:2   a:2   b:2   c:0   
i:3   a:3   b:3   c:0   
========= Program hit cudaErrorInvalidDeviceFunction (error 98) due to "invalid device function" on CUDA API call to cudaLaunchKernel. 
=========     Saved host backtrace up to driver entry point at error
=========     Host Frame:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcuda.so.1 [0x3b9803]
=========     Host Frame:./saitama [0x4a585]
=========     Host Frame:./saitama [0x72b8]
=========     Host Frame:./saitama [0x7071]
=========     Host Frame:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (__libc_start_main + 0xe7) [0x21b97]
=========     Host Frame:./saitama [0x6c1a]
```

Your host code is a strange mixture of device and runtime API which I don't believe can ever work correctly. Modifying your host code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>

int main()
{
    CUdevice device;
    CUcontext context;
    CUmodule module;
    CUfunction function;
    char moduleFile[] = "test.ptx";
    char kernelName[] = "test";

    CUresult err = cuInit(0);
    cuDeviceGet(&device, 0);
    cuCtxCreate(&context, 0, device);

    err = cuModuleLoad(&module, moduleFile);
    if (err != CUDA_SUCCESS) { printf("cuModuleLoad %4d \n", err); return 1; }

    err = cuModuleGetFunction(&function, module, kernelName);
    if (err != CUDA_SUCCESS) { printf("cuModuleGetFunction %4d \n", err); return 1; }

    int size = 4;
    unsigned int byteSize = size * sizeof(int);
    int* h_a = (int*)malloc(byteSize);
    int* h_b = (int*)malloc(byteSize);
    int* h_c = (int*)malloc(byteSize);
    CUdeviceptr d_a; cuMemAlloc(&d_a, byteSize);
    CUdeviceptr d_b; cuMemAlloc(&d_b, byteSize);
    CUdeviceptr d_c; cuMemAlloc(&d_c, byteSize);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        h_a[i] = i;
        h_b[i] = i;
        h_c[i] = 0;
    }
    printf("before\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("i:%-3d a:%-3d b:%-3d c:%-3d \n", i, h_a[i], h_b[i], h_c[i]);

    cuMemcpyHtoD(d_a, h_a, byteSize);
    cuMemcpyHtoD(d_b, h_b, byteSize);
    void* args[]{ &d_a, &d_b, &d_c };
    cuLaunchKernel(function,  1, 1, 1, size, 1, 1, 0, 0, (void**)args, 0);

    cuCtxSynchronize();
    cuMemcpyDtoH(h_c, d_c, byteSize);

    printf("\nafter\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("i:%-3d a:%-3d b:%-3d c:%-3d \n", i, h_a[i], h_b[i], h_c[i]);

    free(h_a);
    free(h_b);
    free(h_c);
    cuMemFree(d_a);
    cuMemFree(d_b);
    cuMemFree(d_c);

    cuCtxDestroy(context);
    return 0;
}
```

gets me this:

```
$ nvcc -o saitama saitama.cu  -lcuda

$ cat test.ptx
//test.ptx
.version 6.4
.target sm_52
.address_size 64

.visible .entry test(
    .param .u64 .ptr .global .align 8 a,
    .param .u64 .ptr .global .align 8 b,
    .param .u64 .ptr .global .align 8 c
)
{
    .reg .u64 %a;
    .reg .u64 %b;
    .reg .u64 %c;
    .reg .u64 %i;

    ld.param.u64 %a, [a];
    ld.param.u64 %b, [b];
    ld.param.u64 %c, [c];
    cvt.u64.u32 %i, %tid.x;
    shl.b64 %i, %i, 2;
    add.u64 %a, %a, %i;
    add.u64 %b, %b, %i;
    add.u64 %c, %c, %i;

    .reg .s32 %s<3>;
    ld.s32 %s0, [%a];
    ld.s32 %s1, [%b];
    add.s32 %s0, %s0, %s1;
    st.s32 [%c], %s0;

    ret;
}

$ cuda-memcheck ./saitama
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
before
i:0   a:0   b:0   c:0   
i:1   a:1   b:1   c:0   
i:2   a:2   b:2   c:0   
i:3   a:3   b:3   c:0   

after
i:0   a:0   b:0   c:0   
i:1   a:1   b:1   c:2   
i:2   a:2   b:2   c:4   
i:3   a:3   b:3   c:6   
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
```

[ Note I needed to change PTX version and target, and never ignore compiler warnings, they are there to help you ].

Comment: Thank you. I am using visual studio 2019 community edition and it had no warnings or errors.

Comment: You don't have proper CUDA error checking in your code.  I believe that if you had used it, your code would have reported the invalid device function error.